# Moving Subdirectories Between Directories by Folder Name

Tags: files, batch-rename

I have a series of sub-directories, all in one parent-directory, each titled like such:

- StringA (Date1) StringW [String10]
- StringB (Date2) StringX [String11]
- StringB (Date3) StringY [String12]
- StringC (Date4) StringZ [String13]

I also have a different folder full of subdirectories, one for each unique string to lead the title of a subdirectory from the prior list. Proceeding from the above example, it would go:

- StringA
- StringB
- StringC

Is there a workable means of moving each extended-title sub-directory into the short-titled sub-directory that matches its leading string?

For clarity, my desired result would be folders nested in the following order:

- StringA/StringA (Date1) StringW [String10]
- StringB/StringB (Date2) StringX [String11]
- StringB/StringB (Date3) StringY [String12]
- StringC/StringC (Date4) StringZ [String13]

Answer (score 0):

Try following script

```
foo="/path/to/folder/containing/short-titled-directories"
bar="/path/to/folder/containing/extended-titled-directories"

for subdir in $foo/*
do
    if [[ -d "$subdir" ]]
    then
        folder_to_move=$(ls $bar | grep "$subdir")
        mv "$bar/$folder_to_move" "$subdir/$folder_to_move"
    fi
done
```